# How to start from second index for for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have this for-loop. I want `i in range(nI)` to start from the second number in the `I` list. Could you guide me?

```
I=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
nI=len(I)
for i in range(nI):
    sum=0
    for v in range(nV):
        for j in range(nJ):
            sum=sum+x1[i][j][v]
return sum
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First thing is to remember that python uses zero indexing.

You can iterate throught the list except using the range function to get the indexes of the items you want or slices to get the elements.

What I think is becoming confusing here is that in your example, the values and the indexes are the same so to clarify I'll use this list as example:

```
I = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
nI = len(I) # 5
```

The range function will allow you to iterate through the indexes:

```
for i in range(1, nI):
    print(i)
# Prints:
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

If you want to access the values using the range function you should do it like this:

```
for index in range(1, nI):
    i = I[index]
    print(i)
# Prints:
# b
# c
# d
# e
```

You can also use array slicing to do that and you don't even need `nI`. Array slicing returns a new array with your slice.
The slice is done with `the_list_reference[start:end:steps]` where all three parameters are optional and:
`start` is the index of the first to be included in the slice
`end` is the index of the first element to be excluded from the slice
`steps` is how many steps for each next index starting from (as expected) the `start` (if `steps` is 2 and start with 1 it gets every odd index).
Example:

```
for i in I[1:]:
    print(i)
# Prints:
# b
# c
# d
# e
```

Answer (score 20):

You can simply use slicing:

```
for item in I[1:]:
    print(item)
```

And if you want indexing, use pythonic-style `enumerate`:

```
START = 1
for index, item in enumerate(I[START:], START):
    print(item, index)
```

Comment: Nice :) you preserved using a Python and C# style forEach rather than a c++ style For with a Range statment.

Comment: This is the way more elegant solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to iterate through a list from a second item, just use `range(1, nI)` (if nI is the length of the list or so).

```
for i in range(1, nI):
    sum=0
    for v in range(nV):
        for j in range(nJ):
            sum=sum+x1[i][j][v]
```

Probaly, a part of your function just lost somewhere, but anyway, in in general range() works like this:

```
range(start_from, stop_at, step_size)
```

i. e.

```
for i in range(2, 7, 2):
    print(i, end=' ')

Out:
2 4 6
```

**Edit**

Please, remember: python uses zero indexing, i.e. first element has an index 0, the second - 1 etc.

By default, `range` starts from 0 and stops at the *value of the passed parameter minus one.* If there's an explicit **start**, iteration starts from it's value. If there's a **step**, it continues while `range` returns values *lesser than* **stop** value.

```
for i in range(1, 7, 2):
    print(i, end=' ')

Out: 
1 3 5  # there's no 7!
```

Detailed description of `range` build-in is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Comment: My range is I=5 but I want to skip 1 from this range and start from i=2 in this range

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the missing part of your code snippet? Guess it's possible to solve it without `range` just with slices.

Comment: I did. I want i starts from 1 in my list. I don't want 0 for my for-loop

Answer (score 2):

Range starts from the 0 index if not otherwise specified. You want to use something like

```
for i in range(1,nI):
    ...
```

Comment: My range is 5 but I want to skip 1 from this range and start from i=2 in this range

Comment: So you want to get the second through fifth items in your list?

Comment: I want my for loop get the index of the second value in the list and do the iteration to end

Comment: I want something like this: for i+1 in range(n)

Answer (score 0):

- You should avoid using names of built-ins. If you really must, add an underscore at the end e.g. sum_, but it's probably a hint that you should be using the built-in instead.
- For iteration variables, it's recommended you use`i, j, k, m, n`unless you have a reason to name it something else.
- If you are using numpy arrays, you can loop over all values using for value in  `np.nditer(...)`
- If you put `sum = 0` inside of the loop, then it'll get reset to that every time.
- You can "de-nest" for loops using itertools.product e.g.

```
sum(x[i][j][v] for i, j, v in itertools.product(range(nI), range(nJ), range(nV)))
```

- To reduce multiple for loops, Itertools has a product function that gives you a generator that will allow you to flatten multiple iterables into one iterable of tuples that effectively is the same as nested for loops. The only difference is ordering of the values.

```
from itertools import product

for x, y in product(range(3), range(4, 7)):
    print(x, y)
```

```
0 4
0 5
0 6
1 4
1 5
1 6
2 4
2 5
2 6

[Program finished]
```