# Remove a number from list of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print(list(range(0, n+1, 10)))
```

So I want to print the list of positive multiples of 10 up to and including n.
But I'm not sure how I would go about removing the `0` when it prints the list as `0` doesn't count as a positive integer. I'm new to programming so the only thing I tried was

```
a = list(range(0, n+1, 10))
a.remove(0)
print(a)
```

But I was wondering whether I could do it all in one line along with `print(list(range(0, n+1, 10)))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start from second index for for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621696/how-to-start-from-second-index-for-for-loop)

Comment: Guess it does but as I've said I'm new to programming and just starting the range at 10 is much simpler. Thank you either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option is to start your range at 10 rather than 0:

```
>>> n = 100
>>> list(range(10, n+1, 10))
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

A more general solution to the problem of "how do I get this range minus this type of number" might be to use a list comprehension instead of the `list()` function, and add an `if` clause:

```
>>> [x for x in range(0, n+1, 10) if x > 0]
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

This lets you do more complex things like "give me all multiples of 10 that are not also multiples of 30":

```
>>> [x for x in range(0, n+1, 10) if x % 30]
[10, 20, 40, 50, 70, 80, 100]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can just simply start at 10 guess I was just over coamplifying things. Thank you for showing me the other methods as well it really helps.

Comment: Might want to add an equality to `if x % 30`. Otherwise, it's a bit misleading to read as non-zero results are returned

Answer (score 3):

`range`, documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), supports different parameters, which are different inputs leading to different outputs as you are likely aware.

The first parameter is the *starting* value, so if you do:

```py
n = 60
list(range(10, n+1, 10))
```

then it will print multiples of 10, starting at 10:

```py
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`a = list(range(10, n+1, 10))`

Comment: that doesn't work no - he is asking for multiples of 10